# Password issue. MYBOOK 2TB Ext USB HDD does not accept my password

Tags: external-hard-drive, storage, mybook

I bought a MY BOOK 2TB External USB data drive for my personal home stand alone computer.

I use windows 8.0pro, the data drive is about 5 years old, does not have any wifi, network capabilities and is not shared with anyone.

I disconnected it from my PC since it crashed/died. I had a new HDD put in, now I plug in my data drive and now it's requesting my password which I am putting in correctly but no matter what password I put in, it will say it's invalid.

How can I get around this password? I do not care about the drive, only about retrieving all of the personal family data I have in it collected over the last ten years!

Comment: https://community.wd.com/t/wd-my-book-essential-2-tb-password-issues/1593  have you tried any of the answers here?

Comment: Hi Thanks, yes I have and had no luck yet. I also contacted a data retrieval place in Ca. they quoted me about $2500.00! I don't have that kind of money since I am disabled, not employed, and no income but live on my wife's income of 12k. Any help, suggestions etc is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That is crazy. Is there a Reset button on it? http://ccm.net/forum/affich-26975-wd-my-book-reset-password could you put the model number in the post please?

Comment: Hi. The model of the external drive is:
Name "My Book" 1110 
There is no resette button anywhere on the drive. The drive can not be access remotely it does not have that capability. 

I bought it from Best Buys about four or five years ago. 

I have no problems with the drive until a few days ago my old computer an HP all in one died and I just had a new Hard drive installed. Now the computer is all up and running like new and my external drive is reconnected and it prompts me for a password. Thank you so much.

Comment: What exactly is prompting for the password? Could you provide a screenshot? I ask, because if this is an ATA password, those can be trivially overridden with utilities. If it's one of the data encryption tools provided by the drive manufacturer, the outlook is not so great.

Comment: Hi. """data encryption tools provided by the drive manufacturer,"" I'm afraid this is true. I used the Microsoft Bit Encryption tool found in control panel. i've installed it on my PC and when I try to access the external data drive that's when I get prompted to enter a  password....It only gives me two options to format the drive or enter a password. If I format I will loose all information 2GB for ever. Thank you

Comment: I don't know how to upload a screen shot to here though.  i know how to make a screen shot but how do I post it here?